# Как сравнить строку и число?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution
{
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //напишите тут ваш код
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String x = null;
    int sum = 0;
    while (true){

        if (x.equals("сумма")){
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;
        }
        else{
            x = reader.readLine();
            sum += Integer.parseInt(x);

        }



    }
  }
}
```

Мой вопрос покажется не корректным (но придумать заголовок не получилось получше) Вот что мне нужно сделать: Вводить с клавиатуры числа и считать их сумму, пока пользователь не введёт слово «сумма». Вывести на экран полученную сумму. Как можно сравнить число со строкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, как-то так будет.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String x;
   int sum = 0;
   while (true){
      x = reader.readLine();
      if (x.equals("sum")) {
         System.out.println(sum);
      } else{
         sum += Integer.parseInt(x);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: IDEA отказывается такое компилить.  Error:(22, 34) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Кажется я догнал вашу мысль спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно сканнером пользуюсь

```
int sum = 0;
String x = "";
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {
        if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += reader.nextInt();
        }
        x = reader.nextLine();
    } while (!x.equals("сумма"));
}
System.out.println("Сумма = " + sum);
```

Тут невалидный ввод (не числа) игнорируется, но можно вывести сообщение какое-то.

Совет: инициализируйте строки пустыми значениями, а не null